# Is there a way to change the font size in webchat either through CSS or C# in the bot framework?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, web-chat

I want the font sizes across webchat which uses microsoft botservices to be the same. The default font size for different elements are not the same, which leads web chat to look strange.

Full-featured bundle with ES5 polyfills the example can be found here: 
 https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.b.getting-started-es5-bundle

I've tried to change the font size with css using

```
*  { 
    font-size: 13px;
   }
```

however this did not hold after I deployed the page which host the chat bot on the server.

All I want is the font size to be consistent accross all my cards and texblocks.

Comment: Can you post an image showing the different sized fonts and if the dialog elements are cards, simple messages, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to alter the font size via styleOptions. You can do this simply by changing the web chat element and all it's children via CSS, like so:

```html
<style>
  html,
  body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    #webchat {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

  #webchat>* {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
</style>
```

Hope of help!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out we were having some caching issues with the web page. After fixing this all of the targeted elements where styled accordingly. We used a combination of styleOptions along with CSS for the desired look and feel of the chat window.

styleOptions can be found here:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.a.branding-webchat-styling

And here:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js

For CSS there are specific classes that can be targeted inside the chat window which can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/net-html/native-styling